# Setting up a macro to copy a range from one worksheet to another in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets and I'm trying to setup a macro in sheet2 which will clear the contents of sheet2 and then copy from sheet6 a range of data (columns A:Q) from row 2 down to the last row of data to the corresponding columns of sheet2 from row 2.  I have found some code which can do the copying but I suspect that it will only work if the source sheet (sheet6) is the active sheet and I need this to be part of a macro to be run on sheet2 as there are other things to be added later to the macro. 
The code I used on sheet2 is this:

```
Sub AImportData()


    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With Sheets("Sheet6")
        .Range("A:Q").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A2")
    End With



End Sub
```

This clears the data in sheet2 but when it gets to the point where it needs to copy the data from sheet6 I get a subscript out of range error.  I have tried to use ActiveWorksheet in my code but then I get an object required error. I need some guidance on this please?

Here, You can see the names of the sheets as shown in the Project Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have WorkSheet label `Sheet6` in the Workbook. I'm not sure your error occured on which line. Please  specified which line you have the problem?

Comment: I added a new part to my answer. Check it and let me know if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between a sheet's name and a sheet's object name. For example, you can see in this pricture that I have a sheet named "Sheet2" while its object's name is "Sheet5"

[image]

To refer to that sheet, you have to do one of the following:

1: Use the sheet name: `Sheets("Sheet2")`

2: Use the sheet's object name: `Sheet5`

3: Use the sheet's number (position): `Sheets(2)`

(The sheet's position will change when you remove sheets that are before this sheet. [For example, when you delete the first sheet, the sheet that was second will now be the first] So, be careful when you use this method.)

So, in your situation, you need to make sure you have a sheet named "Sheet6", or name it correctly.

Another issue you have is that you are trying to copy a set of whole columns (A:Q) to a position that is not a whole columns, but a part of a column starting from row number 2 (A2).

So, you have to do something like this:

```
Sub AImportData()
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3 'Do you really need this?
    With Sheet6
        maxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        .Range("A2:Q" & maxRow).Copy Range("A2")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have used in both cases the object name as you indicated above but still get the same issue.  If I change the - Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") - part to Set ws = Sheets.Sheet2 I get the method or data member not found error message

Comment: I have also tried to replace the object name with the sheet names and then get an application-defined or object -defined error.

Comment: `Set ws = Sheets.Sheet2` is incorrect. You should try `Set ws = Sheet2`. If that doesn't solve it, please edit your question and add a screenshot of object explorer part that shows the sheets' names like the one I added to my answer.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and have no idea how to attach a screenshot.  Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Welcome aboard again :). When you edit your question, go to the position where you want to add the screenshot, then press Ctr + G (or use the image icon in the tools bar of the edit area.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have added the screenshot as requested.

Comment: I have changed my code to look exactly like yours and then get a Run-time error 1004:  Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: oh .. right! you are trying to copy a whole set of columns to a partial set of columns (starting from row number 2) ...

Comment: Actually the source data (Sheet6)  in columns A thru Q starts on row 2 all the way down and should be copied on the target (Sheet2) from row2 down

Comment: I still get the application-defined or object d-defined error

Comment: It's working now thank you so much for your help and patience

Comment: Just a quick question.  I have used this same code on two other sheets and changed the sheet names and relevant ranges but the result only returns the top two lines.  The data I want to copy now is on sheet seven and the target sheet is sheet 1.

Comment: It might be better to create a new question and include the new code, range, and name. Also, the expected result and the bad result.